# Pushout of groupoid

Tags: category-theory, groupoids

I'm learning category theory. There's a homework question asking for a pushout of groupoid.
Suppose $C_0,C_1,C_2$ are groupoids and denote $f_i:C_0\to C_i\quad i=1,2$  the functor.

I have managed to show the objects are $\mathrm{Obj}(C_1 \underset{C_0}{\sqcup}C_2 )=(C_0/\sim)\cup (C_1\backslash f_1^{-1}(C_0))\cup (C_2\backslash f_2^{-1}(C_0))$ where the equivalence is the "closure" of the relation having same images in $C_1$ or $C_2$.

I think that the morphisms can be generated by the morphisms above, but have problems making it clear.

Comment: The morphisms in the pushout are indeed _generated_ by the morphisms in the original groupoids, but because composable morphisms must have a composite there may be morphisms that are not in the image per se. You can give an explicit description but it will be tedious. Perhaps you should ask your teacher what level of detail is appropriate.

Comment: @ZhenLin Yes, actually it confuses me that some composition appears to be the same while I can't find a good expression of the equivalent relation. Would you mind explaining it clearer?

Comment: Basically you need to take the pushout of the underlying graphs then generate the free category on it then quotient out by every composition of the original arrows.

Comment: @Berci Thanks for your comment. Yes, but sometimes different composition will give the same morphism in the pushout. For example, consider the circle using homotopy Van Kampen theorem.